# How do I write top 5 attribute and group by in a linq Expression?

Tags: c#, t-sql

I am trying to find out best 5 company names which makes the max profit for the company.
Here is what I have written so far:

```
var result = from c in db.Customers
             join o in db.Orders
             on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
             join od in db.Order_Details
             on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
             select new
             {
                 CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                 Profit = (float)od.UnitPrice * (float)od.Quantity * (1 - od.Discount)
             };
```

However, it doesn't contain not the group by and the best 5 company part which I'm actually looking for. I tried to do with

```
group c by c.CompanyName into CompanyName
```

but it doesn't work, and I couldn't find out that top 5 company query.

Comment: Top five would be and `OrderBy` followed by a `Take(5)`.

Comment: Which data access library is this? Entity Framework? Please use tags to indicate which it is and which version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to group your result with company name and sum the profit, then take the highest 5 by order by desc and take.

Something like the below (even though the sentence may not be exactly correct)

```
var grouped =from p in query 
            group p by p.CompanyName into g
            select new
            {
              CompanyName = g.Key,
              TotalProfit = g.sum(x=>x.Profit)
            };

var Top5=grouped.orderbyDesc(x=>TotalProfit).take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       var totalCompanies = db.Order_Details.GroupBy(x => x.Order.Customer.CompanyName).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Sum(y=> (float)y.Quantity * (float)y.UnitPrice * 1 - (y.Discount))).Take(5).ToList();

        List<string> bestCompanies = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in totalCompanies)
        {
            bestCompanies.Add(item.Key);
        };
```

Here is the similar solution for the question.